# Recursion in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume we have a table **borders(country1,country2)** that contains two countries that border each other, eg. (Sweden, Norway), etc. I would like to find all the countries that can be reached from a given country, say Sweden, by using border crossing only.

Here's the first part of my solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE border(countryin) AS (
    select distinct country 
    from (select country2::character varying(4) as country 
          from borders where country1 = 'S'  
          union  
          select country1::character varying(4) as country 
          from borders where country2 = 'S' ) a
    UNION 
    select distinct sp.country::varchar(4) 
    from (select country1::varchar(4) as country, country2 as n 
          from borders) sp  
    join (select country2::varchar(4) as country, country1 as n, countryin as temp 
          from borders, border) st 
      on sp.country = st.n 
     and sp.country in st.temp
    where true              
)
SELECT distinct countryin, name 
FROM border, country 
where countryin = code ;
```

The only thing that I cannot get to work is how to set a constraint so that a specific country exists in the result border table. I tried using **and sp.country in st.temp**, and several other ways, but I cannot get it to work.

Could some one give me a hint of how this can be solved?

**Current Results**:

- Right now, I get an error stating "
  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "st"
  LINE 4: ...s, border) st on sp.country = st.n and sp.country in st.temp
  "

**Desired Results**

- List all counties that can be reached recursively using borders starting from 'S'. So, if we have (S,N), (N,R), (R,C), (D,A), we would get: (N,R,C)

Comment: I dont understand the problem can you provide an example of current result and desire output ? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is room for improvement, but seem like do the job.

**base case**, you get the "other" country where 'S' appear in any side

**recursive case** get new country with border with any country already in travel path, but avoid the one with 'S' so doesnt return to origin. Also include a variable to track recursive depth so doesnt keep looping for ever. (dont remember how many country are now).

After finish I add filter `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate.

Maybe I could include a filter on the `recursive case` To avoid travel back to same countries. Not sure which one is more efficient.

```
AND (    b.country1 NOT IN (SELECT country FROM Travel)
     AND b.country2 NOT IN (SELECT country FROM Travel)
    )
```

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c4d9/7)**

```
WITH RECURSIVE travel(r_level, country) AS (
    select distinct 1 as r_level,
                    CASE WHEN country1 = 'S' THEN country2
                         ELSE country1          
                    END as country
    from borders 
    where country1 = 'S' 
       or country2 = 'S'    
    UNION 
    select distinct t.r_level + 1 as r_level,
                    CASE WHEN b.country1 = t.country THEN b.country2
                         ELSE b.country1
                    END as country           
    from borders b
    join travel  t
      ON (b.country1 = t.country OR b.country2 = t.country)
     AND (b.country1 <> 'S' AND b.country2 <> 'S')
    WHERE t.r_level < 300
)
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM travel
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| country |
|---------|
|       N |
|       R |
|       C |
```

Please feel free to provide a more complete sqlFiddle with more country to improve the testing.

Comment: I've tested this on a larger data with loops and it works. I had an alternative solution which eliminated circular dependencies, but your query is much simpler (and after all not less efficient I suppose).

Comment: Thanks @klin good to know. If possible share your solution and the large data I will like to do more testing.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. In my case, the recursion level counter was not necessary, but it's good to have just in case.

Comment: @Artem You need recursion level otherwise recursion never stop.